# How to Upgrade the Erlang version on Ubuntu (R14B04 to latest stable version)?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, upgrade

How to Upgrade Erlang version on Ubuntu (R14B04 to latest stable version)?

Comment: I tend to directly compile the version of Erlang I want on my servers. This allow me to choose the install directory and thus easily share several Erlang versions on the same server.

Answer (score 37):

Determine which one to add according to the result of running the following in the console:

```
lsb_release -c
```

Add one of the following to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu trusty contrib
deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu saucy contrib
deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu precise contrib 
deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu bionic contrib
```

Run the following two commands, after successfully updating the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/erlang_solutions.asc
sudo apt-key add erlang_solutions.asc
```

Then run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install erlang
```

Reference: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html

Comment: Excellent. Solved a TLS problem we had with Rabbit MQ.

Comment: was able to specify `deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu xenial contrib binary-amd64` in `sources.list` in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: `ubuntu bionic contrib` worked for me. Based on what is listed [here](https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/) I assume that xenial and cosmic also work. So I added these to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kerl](http://github.com/yrashk/kerl) to build/install distributions and easily switch between them.